# How to identify which Daemon Process is writing to the file

Tags: unix, process, operating-system, daemon

I need to identify a daemon process that is writing to a log file periodically. The problem is that I dont have any idea which process is doing the job, and I need to show some progress to the client by tomorrow. Anybody has any clue?

I have already sorted out the daemon processes running in the system with the help of the PPID. Any help would be appreciated.

Also I think it is possible (rarely) for a daemon not to have a PPID as 1. How can we find it out then?

Answer (score 6):

Try the [`fuser`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fuser) command on your log file, which will display the PIDs of processes using it.

Example:

```
$ fuser file.log
file.log:  3065
```

Comment: But isn't that valid only if the process keeps the file open?  What if the process only opens the file at the time of writing the data?

Comment: If you don't know when the process writes to the log, you can use `watch` to execute `fuser` periodically. e.g. `watch fuser file.log`.

Comment: that could be possible, ok.. i'll try. The problem is that I dont have write permissions, so cant redirect the output of watch to any file. Lets see what can be done. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: dogbane's comments are good - but watch won't work in all UNIX implementations. What exact OS are we talking about?

Comment: hp-unix. I'll have to man it then I guess.. Any other suggestions?

Comment: If you haven't got `watch`, you can call `fuser` in a `while` loop.

Comment: that will be to resource hogging I would say. The changes will be on a live application.

Comment: Not if you have a time delay in your loop. You can sleep for 2 secs before each iteration, like this: `while [ true ]; do fuser file.log; sleep 2; done > fuser.log`

Answer (score 4):

`lsof` gives a list of open files with the processes.
So `lsof | grep <filename>` should help you.

Comment: apparently lsof isn't available in the system my client has installed. Solaris 8.

Answer (score 4):

You can use auditctl.

```
# sudo apt-get install auditd
# sudo /sbin/auditctl -w /path/to/file  -p war -k hosts-file
-w watch /etc/hosts
-p warx watch for write, attribute change, execute or read events
-k hosts-file is a search key.
# sudo /sbin/ausearch -f /path/to/file | more
```

Gives output such as

type=UNKNOWN[1327] msg=audit(1459766547.822:130): proctitle=2F7573722F7362696E2F61706163686532002D6B007374617274
type=PATH msg=audit(1459766547.822:130): item=0 name="/path/to/file" inode=141561 dev=08:00 mode=0100444 ouid=33 ogid=33 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL
type=CWD msg=audit(1459766547.822:130):  cwd="/"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1459766547.822:130): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=41 a0=7f3c23034cd0 a1=80000 a2=1b6 a3=8 items=1 ppid=24452 pid=6797 auid=42949672
95 uid=33 gid=33 euid=33 suid=33 fsuid=33 egid=33 sgid=33 fsgid=33 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="apache2" exe="/usr/sbin/apache2" key="hosts-file"

Comment: `sudo /sbin/auditctl -D` to turn if off.

Comment: This is the one! Apparently, `lsof` and `fuser` will take forever to stumble upon the opening of the file even in a while loop if the file is written in very short bursts.